# How to merge body part image into one

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have some body part images for user to merge it as nft.

```
-images
 -eyes
  -blue_eyes.png
  -red_eyes.png
 -body
  -strong_body.png
  -slim_body.png
...
```

For example:
[image]

Users can select different body parts to combine.

If I want to let users to see the preview of the avatar, how should I combine the body part images into one like below, using `javascript`?

[image]

Comment: The only way i know is to set ```style.position``` to ```position: absolut``` in your CSS. And than give them all the same coordinates with ```top``` and ```left corner```. I don't know exactly if there is another way to do it but I think this is the only solution.. I will post my solution in the answers..

Comment: For a nft like project I would not recommend doing it on frontend. That defeats the whole 'purpose' of nfts. The idea is that you have an 'unique' kind of art. If you give your building pieces to the frontend everyone can build their own not so unique anymore nft. Therefore rendering the images on your server with something like jimp using `image.composite( src, x, y );`  would be propably best for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know is to use it with HTML and CSS, like this:

*In your HTML*

```
<div class="wrappingImage">
  <img class="overlappingImage" src="body.png">
  <img class="overlappingImage" src="eyes.png">
  <img class="overlappingImage" src="mouth.png">
</div>
```

*In your CSS*

```
.overlappingImage {
  position: absolut:
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.wrappingImage {
  position: relative;
}
```

Than you can add a value (like this: `<img value="1">`) to your `images` and place them based on this value in your `template` after clicking a button - so let `body = 0`, `eyes = 1` and `mouth = 1`.

Hopefully it helps you out!

Answer (score -1):

You can combine the images using `node.js` packages [merge-images](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-images) and [canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas).

```
const mergeImages = require('merge-images');
const { Canvas, Image } = require('canvas');
const fs = require('fs');

const run = async () => {
    const outputBase64 = await mergeImages(['./body.png', './eyes.png', './mouth.png'], {
        Canvas: Canvas,
        Image: Image
    });

    fs.writeFileSync(
        './output.png',
        outputBase64.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, ''), // remove the base64 prefix
        {'encoding': 'base64'}
    );
}

run();
```

Input images:

[image: body]
[image: eyes]
[image: mouth]

Output image:

[image: output]